# Entropy and perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Consider a system which is out of equilibrium. The entropy is given by
$$
S = - \sum_n p_n \log p_n.
$$
But from perturbation theory
$$
\dot{p}_n = \sum_{m} \left( |V_{nm}|^2 p_m - |V_{mn}|^2 p_n \right).
$$

This leads to the conclusion that
$$
\dot{S} = \sum_{n,m} |V_{nm}|^2 \left( p_n - p_m \right) \left(\log p_m - \log p_n \right).
$$

Now this is positive (second law of thermodynamics) but if time is allowed to pass then $S \rightarrow 0$.

This you might think is the equilibrium state of the system. But here all the probabilities are equal $p_n = 1/N$ ($N$ states).

But in equilibrium $p_n \propto e^{- \beta E_n}$ supposedly.

So why is there this contradiction here?

Comment: Boltzmann distribution requires coupling to a heath bath. In that case, for each energy eigenstate state with energy $E$ of the system, the bath can be in a number of states proportional to $\exp(-\beta E)$. All states of the combined system that includes the bath are then equally likely.

Comment: @CountIblis So, is your statement that in any closed system all probabilities are equally likely? Secondly, I was hoping that I had simulated a heath bath in some sense with the effect of the perturbing potential $V$.